# How to go to next changes in VS Code side-by-side view?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can view side-by-side comparison to current and previous file version in VS Code Source Control/Git View. Are there any hotkey's to navigate on my changes i.e. go to next/prev changes from the keyboard just as if I clicked the `Next Change` button?

[image: VS Code Diff View Next Change button]

Unfortunately I haven't found anything about it in the [key binding documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings)

Answer (score 51):

To go to the next difference use <kbd>Alt + F5</kbd>.

To go to the previous difference use <kbd>Shift + Alt + F5</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, those are the settings for me as well, but it does not work.

Comment: On Mac, use the Option (⌥) key instead of the `Alt` key

Answer (score 41):

You are looking for `workbench.action.compareEditor.nextChange`/`previousChange`.

I have it bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd> like this:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+down",
    "command": "workbench.action.compareEditor.nextChange",
    "when": "textCompareEditorVisible"
}
```

Comment: what file are you putting these settings? I'm seeing `Unknown configuration setting` when copying the body of the above dict to the `Workspace Settings`

Comment: The keybindings file. Run the "Open Keyboard Shortcuts" command.w

Comment: Nice, `keybindings.json` the other direction being `workbench.action.compareEditor.previousChange`

Answer (score 11):

**If anyone here for Visual Studio 2019:**

You will go on changes directly in file (In Visual Studio 2019).

**Next Change in current file:**

- You can simply press **F8** Key for go to **Next Change**.

**Previous Change in current file:**

- You can simply press **Shift + F8** Key for go to **Previous Change**.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: how can navigate to the following change when it is in the following file?

Answer (score 6):

`"when": "textCompareEditorVisible"` works perfectly in most cases. But when there is any conflict on the keybinding, `&& isInDiffEditor` is a way, which makes the keybinding work only in diff editor.

```
{
    "key": "cmd+up",
    "command": "workbench.action.compareEditor.previousChange",
    "when": "textCompareEditorVisible && isInDiffEditor"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+down",
    "command": "workbench.action.compareEditor.nextChange",
    "when": "textCompareEditorVisible  && isInDiffEditor"
}
```

In my case, my keybindings in integrated terminal will be broken if I don't append the condition

Answer (score 6):

The default on OSX/mac is `alt + F5` for next and `alt + shift + F5` for previous.

Note: 
Make sure you have deactivated your fn keys on mac, so you can fully use VS-Codes shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: Cool does work for me :) But only loops in a file.. how to jump to next file difference? 