# How to go to next changes in VS Code but do not wrap around?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When the search reaches the end of the document, I do not want to wrap around from the beginning and continue searching. Is this possible?

I want to do what is described here [How to go to next changes in VS Code side-by-side view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998311/how-to-go-to-next-changes-in-vs-code-side-by-side-view) but just disable wrap around.