Can I navigate to a the next modified line in vs-code?

In vs-code, is there a way to navigate to the next modified line by a shortcut? Like in the image above, the 102nd line.
I searched in the keyboard shortcuts list and found no such thing. I am not sure is there a command which I can use to make keyboard shortcut.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55654037/836330 - looks like a duplicate.
